# Полоса прокрутки в datalist

Tags: html, css

Есть список реализован с помощью  `datalist`

```
<input list="id" name="name">
  <datalist id="id">
    <option value="name1">name1</option>
    <option value="name2">name2</option>
    <option value="name3">name3</option>
  </datalist>
```

Список получается очень длинный, а скроллинга не появляется.

Все что нашел в интернете перепробовал `style="overflow-y: scroll;"` и другое не работает.

Здесь был задан такой же вопрос [cсылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042745/scroll-bar-for-datalist-in-html5)

В настоящее время datalist не поддерживает стиль CSS, это было 3 года назад, можно ли сейчас сделать скроллинга ?

Comment: недавно бился с той же проблемой. Лучше использовать сторонние js реализации.